# Laravel: Action @index not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

> InvalidArgumentException Action BookingController@index not defined.

In my web.php I have used the following code:

```
Route::resource('bookings', 'App\Http\Controllers\BookingController');
```

I've also tried the following:

```
Route::resource('bookings', 'App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@index');
```

Full code of web.php: https://pastebin.com/SGGr3uAm

In my BookingController.php (relevant code):

```
    public function index()
    {
        $bookings = DB::table('bookings')->get();
        return view('bookings.index')
        ->with('bookings', $bookings);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $id = DB::table('bookings')->insertGetId([
            'room_id' => $request->input('room_id'),
            'start' => $request->input('start'),
            'end' => $request->input('end'),
            'is_reservation' => $request->input('is_reservation', false),
            'is_paid' => $request->input('is_paid', false),
            'notes' => $request->input('notes'),

        ]);
        DB::table('bookings_users')->insert([
        'booking_id' => $id,
        'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),

        ]);
        return redirect()->route('BookingController@index');
    }


    public function update(Request $request, Booking $booking)
    {
        DB::table('bookings')
        ->where('id', $booking->id)
        ->update([
            'room_id' => $request->input('room_id'),
            'start' => $request->input('start'),
            'end' => $request->input('end'),
            'is_reservation' => $request->input('is_reservation', false),
            'is_paid' => $request->input('is_paid', false),
            'notes' => $request->input('notes'),

        ]);
        DB::table('bookings_users')
        ->where('booking_id', $booking->id)
        ->update([
        'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),

        ]);
        return redirect()->route('BookingController@index');
    }

    public function destroy(Booking $booking)
    {
        DB::table('bookings_users')->where('booking_id', $booking->id)->delete();
        $booking->delete();
        return redirect()->action('BookingController@index');

    } }
```

Full code of BookingController.php: https://pastebin.com/TyXpdpH6

I'm using Laravel 8.19.0

php artisan route:list
[image]
What could be the issue? Thanks!!

Comment: please provide `php artisan route:list`

Comment: show please whole code of the controller and routes (web.php)

Comment: I've added the code and a screenshot of php artisan route:list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One must either use the `Route::resource()` method or define the routes manually - don't club them for the same methods.

Remove all other route definitions from the `web.php` file for the `bookings` resource and just keep the Route::resource() one

```php
//routes/web.php

Route::resource('bookings', BookingController::class);
```

Then in the terminal run

```sh
php artisan route:clear

php artisan route:list
```

Then check in the output, you should be able to see the entry for `index`

Comment: It is indeed listed in the route:list now. However, now I get the error that it can't find my functions:  Route [BookingController@show] not defined. (View: /home/vagrant/code/resources/views/bookings/index.blade.php) code: href="{{ route('BookingController@show', ['booking' => $booking->id]) }}

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead,

```
public function destroy(Booking $booking)
{
    DB::table('bookings_users')->where('booking_id', $booking->id)->delete();
    $booking->delete();
    return redirect()->route('bookings.index');

}
```

Comment: I'm retrieving the following error: "Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [bookings.index] not defined. "

Comment: As per your route list, it is not shows the index method. So please remove all unnecessary routes. As if you use resource it should include 7 standard methods. Perfect one is this, `Route::resource('bookings', BookingController::class);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the class and then use it like this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\BookingController;

Route::resource('bookings', BookingController::class);
```

Comment: I've added it to the post

Comment: You have to have only one line declaring the resource routes. Delete this lines: `Route::get('bookings', 'App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@show');
Route::get('bookings', 'App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@update');
Route::get('bookings', 'App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@destroy');`

Answer (score 0):

add

```
use App\Http\Controllers\BookingController;
```

then refer it like this

```
return redirect()->route(BookingController::class,'index');
```

I had the same problem, I fixed it using that

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that all the routes are different

wrong

```php
Route::post('/Remove','App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@Remove1');
Route::post('/Remove','App\Http\Controllers\Task2Controller@Remove2');
```

right

```php
Route::post('/Remove1','App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@Remove1');
Route::post('/Remove2','App\Http\Controllers\Task2Controller@Remove2');
```

it doesn't have to be the same as the function name
you could also do something like this

```php
Route::post('/Task/Remove','App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@Remove2');
```